# How can I break down table's cells on small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    

<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>close</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
      <b>12.6k</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
      <b>1</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Please resize the page. As you see, green box comes out of the red box on a small screen.

Anyway I want to break down both `div.author` and `div.editor` together when the parent's width is smaller than childs' width. Is doing that possible?

Comment: try it with bootstrap?

Comment: @MKAD No, I don't use bootstrap

Comment: okay then you have to use @media queries look at example from Teshtek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` instead of `display: table`.

To wrap editor and author divs together you can use the script below. It will be working even if you put your table into a div with restricted width.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwqznqc4/1/)

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  setTableDirection();
});

setTableDirection();

function setTableDirection() {
  var $table = $('.table');

  if ($table.width() <= 580) {
    $table.css('flex-direction', 'column');
  } else {
    $table.css('flex-direction', 'row');
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.table>div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="table">
    <div class="share_edit_flag">
      <span>share</span>
      <span>edit</span>
      <span>close</span>
    </div>

    <div class="editor">
      <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
        <b>12.6k</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="author">
      <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="#" />
        <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
        <b>1</b>
        <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. Just one thing: both `div.autho`r and `div.editor` are dependent. So they should jump down together. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: I've made some changes, so you can recheck it now :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid green;
  min-width: 190px;
  float:left;
}
  .table > div:nth-child(1){
     clear: both;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    

<div class="table">
  <div class="share_edit_flag">
    <span>share</span>
    <span>edit</span>
    <span>close</span>
  </div>

  <div class="editor">
    <a href="#">edited May 21 16 at 11:58</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">Rory O'Kane</a>
      <b>12.6k</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="author">
    <a href="#">asked May 21 16 at 11:51</a>
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="#" />
      <a href="#">vasanthkumarmani</a>
      <b>1</b>
      <!-- I don't have any badge in my website -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I used media queries and also nth-child of your table > div, I supposed it go overflow under 480px. I think is better for you to use display flex or bootstrap grid system  . For evry question I'm here.I hope you understand and also sorry for my english :)

Here a fiddle you can resize and see the difference : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hgdL8zg/)

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. Just one thing: both `div.author` and `div.editor` are dependent. So they should jump down together. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: Anyway this works but is not a great solution,it's embedded for this situtation but I suggest to use display:flex or bootstrap grid that is more general

Comment: @Teshtek Your solution will not be working on large screens (> 480px) if the table container will have restricted width: https://jsfiddle.net/f8rg933u/

Comment: I know it was just for restricted screen